# Create a dataframe by fixing rows in one column and repeating other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, expand

Lets say I have three variables:

```
var1<-c(101,102,103,104)
var2<-c("AB","XY")
var3<-c(1,2)

X<-expand.grid(var1,var2,var3)
X
```

Above code gives this output

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1   101   AB    1
2   102   AB    1
3   103   AB    1
4   104   AB    1
5   101   XY    1
6   102   XY    1
7   103   XY    1
8   104   XY    1
9   101   AB    2
10  102   AB    2
11  103   AB    2
12  104   AB    2
13  101   XY    2
14  102   XY    2
15  103   XY    2
16  104   XY    2
```

What I need is the series below in which for each row value in var1 we have corresponding values in var2 and var3.

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1   101  AB  1
2   101  XY  2
3   102  AB  1
4   102  XY  2
5   103  AB  1
6   103  XY  2
7   104  AB  1
8   104  XY  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using the `tidyr` package, you can use the `crossing` function. For example

```
tidyr::crossing(var1, tibble::tibble(var2, var3))
#    var1 var2   var3
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1   101 AB        1
# 2   101 XY        2
# 3   102 AB        1
# 4   102 XY        2
# 5   103 AB        1
# 6   103 XY        2
# 7   104 AB        1
# 8   104 XY        2
```

Comment: How can we disable sorting of column values?

Comment: Try `tidyr::expand_grid` rather than `crossing` in that case. note the `_` rather than `.`